# regex match where order of substrings doesn't matter

Tags: regex

have a problem in using regexp. I have a code of the following format.

```
(01)123456789(17)987654321
```

Now I want to capture the digits after `(01)` in a named group: `group01` and the digits after `(17)` in a namedGroup: `group17`.

the problem is that the code could be in different order like this:

```
(17)987654321(01)123456789
```

the named groups should contain the same content.

any ideas?

thank you Marco

Comment: if any of these answers worked, could you accept one?

Answer (score 1):

In  Python, PCRE and PHP

```
(?:(?<=\(17\))(?<group17>\d+)|(?<=\(01\))(?<group01>\d+)|.)+
```

.Net supports the above syntax and this one:

```
(?:(?<=\(17\))(?'group17'\d+)|(?<=\(01\))(?'group01'\d+)|.)+
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
(?<group01>\(01\))[0-9]{9}|(?<group17>\(17\))[0-9]{9}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this regex will match if only one of the two groups are present.  If you always need both but order is irrelevant, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be hardcoding "01" and "17".  Here's a more general solution:

```
while ( my $data =~ /\((\d+)\)(\d+)/g ) {
    my $group_number = $1;
    my $group_data   = $2;
    $group{$group_number} = $group_data;
}
```

As long as you have unsatisfied `(numbers)numbers` patterns matching in your data, it will grab each one in succession.  In this Perl snippet, it stores each group's data into a hash keyed on the group number.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't say what language, they all have their own quirks. But something like this should work if there is always 9 digits after the (). ( In Ruby)

No groups, but its a little clearer like this, in my opinion, may not  work for you.

```
string = "(01)123456789(17)987654321"
group17 = string =~ /\(17\)\d{9}/
group01 = string =~ /\(01\)\d{9}/

string[group17+4,9]
string[group01+4,9]
```

EDIT: 
with named capture groups in ruby 1.9:

```
string = "(01)123456789(17)987654321"
if string =~ /\(17\)(?<g17>\d{9})/
  match = Regexp.last_match 
  group17 = match[:g01]
end
if string =~ /\(01\)(?<g01>\d{9})/
  match = Regexp.last_match 
  group01 = match[:g01]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeking for something like this?

```
(01|17)(\d*?)(01|17)(\d*?)
```

Expected matches:
0 => In most cases the whole match
1 => 01 or 17
2 => first decimal string
3 => second 01 or 17
4 => second decimal string

Tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

Glib quotes aside, regex seems like overkill. Python code:

```
string = "(17)987654321(01)123456789"

substrings = [s for s in string.split("(") if len(s) > 0]

results = dict()

for substring in substrings:
    substring = substring.split(")")
    results["group" + substring[0]] = substring[1]

print results

>>> {'group17': '987654321', 'group01': '123456789'}
```